# "undefined" when evaluating two string variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This program seems to work fine until I have two inputs that are strings. The result that is given back is "undefined". Why is this the case? How could I get the output to be: return "Can\'t compare relationship because "+ x +" and "+ y +" are not numbers"?

```
function getRelationship(x, y) {
        var notDigit = isNaN(x) + isNaN(y);
        if(x==y && notDigit==false){
            return "=";
        }else if(x>y && notDigit==false){
            return ">";
        }else if(x<y && notDigit==false){
            return "<";
        }else if(notDigit==true){
            return notNumber(x,y);
        };
    };
    function notNumber(x, y) {
        xNotDigit = isNaN(x);
        yNotDigit = isNaN(y);
        if(xNotDigit == true){
            return "Can\'t compare relationship because "+ x +" is not a number"
        }else if(yNotDigit == true){
            return "Can\'t compare relationship because "+ y +" is not a number"
        }else if(xNotDigit == true && yNotDigit == true){
            return "Can\'t compare relationship because "+ x +" and "+ y +" are not numbers"
        };
    };

    console.log(getRelationship("Dfad","Dfd"));
```

Comment: Um, what is this? `isNaN(x) + isNaN(y)` ??? And btw don't do `== true`. It's redundant.

Comment: That's used for the case when both x and y are a number. I can't do that?

Comment: `isNaN` returns a boolean, and you are adding a boolean to another boolean, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that `isNaN('Test') + isNaN('Test')` is equal to 2, not true. This is because when you try to cast `true` to a number, by adding it to another number, it casts to 1. So `isNaN('Test') + isNaN('Test')` gets executed as `1 + 1`. Try changing `notDigit` to

```
var notDigit = isNaN(x) || isNaN(y);
```